# upload jar in artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am new to artifactory, I need to upload new version of jar in the repository, here are the steps I am following:

**login to artifactory--> deploy tab--> choose file--> upload--> the target repository I am seeing are**

1. plugins-releases-local
2. libs-releases-local
3. libs-snapshots-local
4. plugins-snapshots-local
5. ext-releases-local
6. ext-snapshots-local

I uploaded my new jar in number 2 (libs-releases-local),
it shows that it is in virtual repository repo and lib-releases,
but older version of same jar has virtual repository repo, remote-repos, libs-releases, plugins-releases, libs-snapshots, plugins-snapshots

I am not sure how do I do the same with my new versioned jar,

also when I search for jar by name for older version it appears in folder repo1-cache while for new version it appears in libs-releases-local

can anyone help me in this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older version came from `repo1`. That's why it appears in `repo1-cache`, `remote-repos`, etc.

You have uploaded your version to a local repository (btw, `ext-release-local` seems like a better fit for this kind of artifact), that's why it appears on only on subset the virtual repositories.

Either way, if you want to use this artifact as a dependency in your build you should configure your build tool to use `libs-releases`, which contain both `libs-releases-local` and `repo1-cache`.